# Scala group by list of list and subtracts grouped values

Tags: scala

Below sample data

```
val combineList = List(("A",12),("B",11),("C",12),("D",14),("E",23),("F",12),("D",53),("C",23),("B",12),("A",22),("E",21),("F",12),("C",21),("B",34),("A",34),("G",67),("D",23),("E",21),("F",12),("D",31),("B",41),("E",14),("F",15),("G",18),("A",11),("C",10),("D",9),("A",13),("E",1),("F",14))
```

and

```
val X = 98
```

Now want final output as below,

first group by all values as below

```
val groupKey = List(Map("A"->List(12,22,34,11,13)),Map("B"->List(11,12,34,41)),Map("C"->List(12,23,21,10)),Map("D"->List(14,53,23,31,9)),
Map("E"->List(23,21,21,14,1)),Map("F"->List(12,12,12,15,14)),Map("G"->List(67,18)))
```

Second substract `X` from `groupKey` List values here `X` always gretter than List values so second output will be as

```
 val substrackValues =  List(Map("A"->List(86,76,34,87,85)),Map("B"->List(87,86,34,57)),Map("C"->List(86,75,77,88)),Map("D"->List(84,45,75,31,89)),
Map("E"->List(75,77,77,84,97)),Map("F"->List(86,86,86,15,84)),Map("G"->List(31,80)))
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, since it sounds like it worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
combineList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(xs => xs.map(v => X-v._2))
```

which delivers

```
Map(E -> List(75, 77, 77, 84, 97), F -> List(86, 86, 86, 83, 84), A -> List(86, 76, 64, 87, 85), G -> List(31, 80), B -> List(87, 86, 64, 57), C -> List(86, 75, 77, 88), D -> List(84, 45, 75, 67, 89))
```

Note the embedded maps in `groupKey` above are *singleton* maps which can well be represented with tuples of `[(String,List[Int])]` or even better agglomerated into one map.

In the solution proposed here after grouping by first tuple element, we transform each element in each list by the value of `X`.

Comment: it work but little changed in your code `combineList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(xs => xs.map(v => X-v._2))`